# Block bootstrap for time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, hidden-markov-models

I'm using the function `tsbootstrap()` from the package `tseries` to generate block bootstrap samples, and to calculate the standard errors for the estimate of the parameters of a regime-switching autoregressive model (which I can obtain using the function `msmFit()` from the package `MSwM`).

Here is the code I'm using. Firstly I define a function for the statistic I want to use:

```
switching.par <- function(z) {
    n<-length(z)
    x<-z[1:(n-1)]
    y<-z[2:n]
    my.xy<- data.frame(x,y)
    mod<-lm(y~x,data=my.xy)
    mod.mswm=msmFit(mod,k=2,sw=c(T,T,T))

    b1 <- mod.mswm@Coef[1,2]
    b2 <- mod.mswm@Coef[2,2]

    c1 <- mod.mswm@Coef[1,1]
    c2 <- mod.mswm@Coef[2,1]

    del1 <- mod.mswm@std[1]
    del2 <- mod.mswm@std[2]

    parameters<-c(b1, b2, c1, c2, del1, del2)
    names(parameters)<-c("b1", "b2", "c1", "c2", "del1", "del2")
    parameters
}
```

And then I use the `tsbootstrap()` function (where `x` is a monthly time series of 10-year US government bonds)

```
use.boot <- tsbootstrap(x, nb=1000, statistic=switching.par, type="block", b=9)
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Error in solve.default(res$Hessian) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[4,4] = 0
```

Any insight on how to fix this problem? I think the error comes from the  function `msmFit()` of the package.

Comment: The error is just saying that you try to **invert** a singular matrix! Otherwise without `x` We can't reproduce your error.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. But I don't know how to fix it. My dataset can be downloaded from this link: https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/IRLTLT01USM156N/downloaddata

Comment: and what about `msmFit` ? try to create a reproducible example we should only copy and paste your code to recreate the bug. I would also create another sample of x to see if I have the same problem using another data( personaly I will not download data to my machine like this) .Really you should better investigate the problem.

Comment: Can do also copy-paste from here: https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/data/IRLTLT01USM156N.txt. I'll try to work on a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error as you correctly understood comes from the `msmFit` function that fails to converge.

I will give a bit of insight as to the error and then provide a solution that worked for me:

`solve.default` is a common error that you can see when an optimiser is being used. Usually the optimiser (such as `optim`) will try to calculate the hessian matrix in order to 'direct' itself to the optimal solution that minimises the underlying function. At some point the hessian matrix needs to be inverted and if it is [singular](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularMatrix.html) the algorithm crashes. Practically this means that the optimiser failed to converge (i.e. couldn't find a solution).

This can be because of a number of reasons:

- Too few observations
- Bad starting values
- Bad design of the function to be optimised (or used in the function)
- Low number of maximum iterations
- Literally no solution for the problem

Now let's go to your problem:

It seems that the default maximum iterations for `msmFit` is 100. Try increasing that to 500 as I do below. The design of the function seems ok to me. Now let's go to the low number of observations. The `b` argument of the `tsbootstrap` function as far as I understand from the documentation is a value that controls the observations that go to the switch function. Having it to 9 makes the `msmFit` function fail. I increased that to 50 (assuming that your df has 50 observations. Anything less than that will probably fail all the time). Also, having it produce 1000 bootstrap series will take a day to compute (at least on my machine).

With all the above in mind, the following seems to work on my machine (for just 10 bootstrap series) and it took ages.

```
switching.par <- function(z) {
  n<-length(z)
  x<-z[1:(n-1)]
  y<-z[2:n]
  my.xy<- data.frame(x,y)
  mod<-lm(y~x,data=my.xy)
  mod.mswm=msmFit(mod,k=2,sw=c(T,T,T), control=list(maxiter=500))

  b1 <- mod.mswm@Coef[1,2]
  b2 <- mod.mswm@Coef[2,2]

  c1 <- mod.mswm@Coef[1,1]
  c2 <- mod.mswm@Coef[2,1]

  del1 <- mod.mswm@std[1]
  del2 <- mod.mswm@std[2]

  parameters<-c(b1, b2, c1, c2, del1, del2)
  names(parameters)<-c("b1", "b2", "c1", "c2", "del1", "del2")
  parameters
}


use.boot <- tsbootstrap(x, nb=10, statistic=switching.par, type="block", b=50)
```

Output:

```
> str(use.boot)
List of 5
 $ statistic     : num [1:10, 1:6] -0.0275 -0.1692 -0.0199 -0.0587 -0.0763 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "t1" "t2" "t3" "t4" ...
 $ orig.statistic: Named num [1:6] 0.0114 -0.1002 0.5155 0.5319 0.2868 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "t1" "t2" "t3" "t4" ...
 $ bias          : Named num [1:6] -0.2029 0.2041 0.0307 -0.0217 -0.036 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "t1" "t2" "t3" "t4" ...
 $ se            : Named num [1:6] 0.2076 0.1774 0.1686 0.1375 0.0533 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "t1" "t2" "t3" "t4" ...
 $ call          : language tsbootstrap(x = x, nb = 10, statistic = switching.par, b = 50, type = "block")
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "resample.statistic"
```

Comment: That's a great answer. However, I'm a bit concerned about the bootstrap. It is 50 a good length for b? I read it should be approximately n^(1/3) (I have around 700 data points). Moreover, I think I will need more than 10 bootstrap series to have something significant from a statistical point of view. -- I just tried with 500 iterations, b=50, and 100 bootstrap series: it gives again error. Using 10 bootstrap works even with my previous input for iterations and b.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see any great answer here. This is a long *approximate* answer to a **non reproducible question** ( a lot of guess )

Comment: The idea of increasing b is not bad. I just tried b=100 and 100 bootstrap series. It works. Now it's more a statistical question if this is a lecit choice for b.

Comment: @Egodym Thanks for your comments :). That's the idea, that you need to 'play' with the arguments of pretty much any function that involves optimization in order to get it to converge. Providing a bigger number of observations and increasing the number of iterations will increase the chances of getting it to converge. I have been in the situation of thinking what would be the best choices for specific arguments (eg. should b be 50 or smaller?) but unfortunately you need to be able to find a computational solution apart from a good statistical one.

Comment: The question is 100% reproducible and well worded by the way. I don't see why anyone would think otherwise. And all of the answers concerning optimization questions are kind of approximate. In the end having a generic answer that would potentially work under many users seeing this answer (including of course the OP) is better IMO than narrowing it down to an 1-line answer that would only help the current situation.

Comment: By using `k=3` in the `msmFit()` function it's even harder to get it to converge. Any hint about how to deal with that?

Comment: @Egodym I am not really an expert with the `msmFit` function and the documentation is not very helpful for me for understanding what it does. Maybe stats.exchange.com would be a better place to ask about this. The above criteria remain the same though. Anything that would internally in `msmFit` reduce the number of observations or increase the number of parameters to estimate would result in lowering the chances of convergence.